# SQL Server Installation freezes

Tags: sql-server, failed-installation, windows-server-2016

I am currently trying to install SQL Server 2017 Enterprise on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter.

When the installation reaches "Install Setupfiles", the window freezes.

I have tried to install SQL Server 2016 Enterprise and SQL Server 2016 Developer, but no difference.

I also have installed .Net Framework 4.7 to meet the requirements of the setup, but nothing changed.

There is also no information from the setup, despite the fact that it skips downloading and extracting the installation files (which is fine, due to the fact that I downloaded a full ISO), but it also skips "installing installation files".

Did I forget any crucial software or setting ?

Did anyone face the same problem ?

Best regards,

Comment: Are you trying to install a pirated version?

Comment: No, I have got a valid license. I also tried the installation with a web installer from https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/sql-server/sql-server-2017, but it kept loading forever.

Comment: I dont know exactly what caused the problem. Maybe it got blocked due to some installed features. I have reinstalled the whole system and it works completely fine now